# Compatibility of P-frames and multithreading in FFmpeg library in C

Tags: c, multithreading, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am working on a video processing project using the FFmpeg library in C. I would like to inquire about the compatibility and support for utilizing P-frames (predictive frames) and multithreading simultaneously in FFmpeg. Currently, I am exploring two options for achieving multithreading with FFmpeg:

1. Setting the i_threads parameter of FFmpeg to a value greater than 1.
2. My application opens multiple threads, where each thread creates a codec context
   and performs parallel compression/decompression of frames from a shared FIFO.

**I have tried option 1**, but I did not observe any noticeable time difference compared to using only one thread. I am seeking an understanding of why this might be the case.

**I have tried option 2**, which has resulted in improved compression/decompression times for the frames. However, I would like to understand why does it work. Since I am utilizing P-Frames, where each P-frame depends on the latest I-Frame, how can I ensure that the decompression of P-Frames starts after the I-Frame has finished processing when dealing with multiple codec contexts?

I have two proceccses one for encodeing and one for decoding.
I'd like to improve times using threads in both of them.

The encoder process code:

`pt_handle->t_x264_param.i_threads = 24;`

`pt_handle->pt_x264_encoder = x264_encoder_open(&pt_handle->t_x264_param);`

The decoder process code:

`pt_handle->pt_avcodec_ctx->thread_count = 23;`

`pt_handle->pt_avcodec_ctx->thread_type = FF_THREAD_FRAME ;`

`i_retval = avcodec_open2(pt_handle->pt_avcodec_ctx, pt_h264_decoder, NULL);`

Comment: Threading parallelization may be used in multiple ways. Threading is not limited to encoding multiple frames in parallel (not limited to encoding full frame in one thread). Most of the encoding stages allows parallelization within a single frame (I-Frame, P-Frame or B-Frame). For libx264 encoder it's difficult to find documentation. [x265 options](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html) describes multiple threading options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is not possible with FFmpeg.

For option 1: you need to set [`thread_type`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#a7651614f4309122981d70e06a4b42fcb) along with [`thread_count`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#aa852b6227d0778b62e9cc4034ad3720c). (There is no `i_threads` parameter.) The result will depend on what encoder you're using and whether it supports threading to begin with (see [`CODEC_CAP_*_THREADS`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.11/group__lavc__core.html#gf7d97232f50d2c3aeb4bde978407f2da)). If you see no improvement, please mention what encoder you're using and what other parameters you set, i.e. please show code.

Comment: I used option 2 for few yeas. now I added the P-frames support.
Do you mean it is not possible due to the  P-Frames?

Comment: I have tried to set `thread_type` and `thread_count` 
If I'm playing a videdo without P-Frames it works and I'm getting the desired FPS
But if I'm playing a recording with P-Frames i'm getting error `avcodec_receive_frame failure`
Do you know if the option of thread_cuuont should work with P-Frames?

Comment: Option 2 is indeed not possible with P frames. When using intra-only coding, FFmpeg can do internally what you're doing (see `frame_thread_encoder.c`). Just set `thread_count` and `thread_type` and you should be good. Your original question suggests you're trying to encode. Here, the error message suggests you're decoding. These 2 are very different, so please clarify what you're trying to do and what codec. Please also share code.

Comment: Sorry for confusen, I added code to the main question

Comment: I've used threading in H264 using variants of the same code, so it's unclear why that would not work for you. Is it possible that when you say "1 thread", you did not set `thread_count` (as opposed to setting it to 1), which would cause it to auto-detect and use practically same amount of threads ("a lot")?

Comment: I got the errors only when I tried to decode a stream with P-frames.
"1 thread" I mean `pt_handle->pt_avcodec_ctx->thread_count = 1` and it worked for me also with P-Frames.
Did you use P-Frames?

Comment: P frames are supported with threading and I have used them succesfully, yes.

Comment: Thanks now it is working for me.
But I have a limitation for the encoder and it works only with 1 frame.
In this case the  decoder fails on `avcodec_receive_frame failure - Resource temporarily unavailable`
if I change the encoder thread counter to 2 the decoder works.
Any idea why?

Comment: you need to send multiple frames before you call receive frame. Call send_data until it returns -EAGAIN, and then call receive_frame. At end-of-file, call receive_frame until -EAGAIN to flush the decoder queue.

Comment: Is it possible that option1 is slower than option 2 using the same number of threads?

Comment: Depends on how it's implemented. If you're using something like chunked encoding (with concurrency coming from encoding multiple chunks at a time - each single-threaded), option 2 will be faster. But within a chunk, they would be equally fast.

Comment: Thanks, I just had another slow operation in the flow